# AWS Route53 Health Check: How to allow ip's on all instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, aws-security-group

I have an ec2 instance with its own security group. I am trying to setup Route 53 health checks.
For this to work, I need to allow the traffic originating from route 53 health check ip's into my instance.

As indicated in the official documentation
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover-router-firewall-rules.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/route-53-ip-addresses.html

I have taken the ip's mentioned in the json and added to the inbound rule of the security group(to which the instance belong). This is working fine.

But I have many instances running with its own security group. I do not want to edit each security group to make the same changes. Is there an easier or simpler way to achieve this?

Comment: Depends. Are the instances in same VPC? If yes, then they can use same SG.

Comment: While these IPs might not change often, they are technically dynamic so you should consider creating Security Group ingress rules that are dynamically populated with the Route 53 IPs. Create that mechanism and then you can more easily apply it to all relevant Security Groups (e.g. via Scheduled Lambda).

Comment: @Marcin they are in same vpc

Answer (score 0):

Assume you don't have NACL configured in the subnet, you just need to create a separate Security Group which allow the requests from Route53 Health Check.

As EC2 Instances and Security Groups are in many-to-many relationship, that mean you can attach instances to multiple security groups, so as a Security Group can be attached by multiple instances.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can go with Manage Prefix list for your case. Because Amazon Route53  supports AWS Managed Prefix lists for health checks. So you don't need to update anything in Security group. Editing security group is not good practice. Just create a managed prefix lists in VPC console and associate any IP address ranges on there. Then you can mapped the managed prefix lists to your target security group. You can use below link to check.

[Managed Prefix lists for AWS Route53 Healthchecks](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/09/amazon-route-53-managed-prefix-lists-health-checks/#:%7E:text=Managed%20prefix%20lists%20for%20Route,or%20maintain%20prefix%20lists%20themselves.)